# Image load when the element comes into the viewport only

Tags: jquery, viewport, image-loading

I am building a photo gallery and i wants to load the images only when the content "DIV" element comes into the viewport.I am using jquery viewport.js for this.

By default i am setting the src attribute of each "IMG" tag to "LOADING.JPEG" and when any div comes into the viewport i change the src attribute of IMG tag to the real image.But after changing the SRC attribute image do not change it still shows the LOADING.JPEG.

```
$(".content").each(function(i,obj){
     var element = obj.id;
     if($("#"+element).is(':in-viewport')){
         var link = $("#"+element+" div a").attr('href');
         //set the image src from loading to read image
         $("#"+element+" div a img").attr('src',link);
     }
});
```

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Why you are making it complex - ?  Try this -

```
$(".content").each(function(i,obj){  
     if($(this)).is(':in-viewport')){
         var link = $("div a",this).attr('href');
         //set the image src from loading to read image
         $("div a img",this).prop('src',link);
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mohammad for your reply , its my html structure , and yes we can do it also as you suggested.But it changes the image src tag but do not refresh the imgae.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [Lazy Load jQuery plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)?

This will gently fade in some images when they are in viewport. Easy enough to setup too, you just call in a data attribute for each image:

```
<img class="lazy" data-original=“img/example.jpg” src=“img/grey.gif” width=“640” height=“480”>
```

and initiate it like it so:

```
$("img.lazy").lazyload();
```